# Is there a way for NHibernate to inform query cache from views to be invalidated?

Tags: nhibernate

I made a view out of joined tables, and I wanted its 2nd level query cache to be invalidated when the view's base table(s) are updated(within ORM context). The view is mapped like a table on NHibernate

Is this possible on NHibernate? How this is done on xml mapping? Fluent mapping will do too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Believe or not, even this is possible with `NHibernate`. If you'd have for example class mapped like this:

```
<class name="Contact" table="[dbo].[Contact]" lazy="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write" region="ShortTerm"/>
```

And there is a view on top of the table `[dbo].[Contact]` which is mapped to another class:

```
<class name="ViewContact" table="[dbo].[ViewContact]" lazy="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write" region="ShortTerm"/>
    <!-- at this moment the View and table are treated differently -->
```

Then the magic setting goes directly under the `<cache>` and and is called **`<synchronize>`**

```
<class name="ViewContact" table="[dbo].[ViewContact]" lazy="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write" region="ShortTerm"/>
    <synchronize table="[dbo].[Contact]"/>
    <!-- now both caches are synchornized -->
```

And now, any changes to mapped class *Contact* will also trigger the cache cleaning of the *ViewContact* class mapped to the view

Comment: +1, you learn something everyday.... Never knew a cache region could be shared this way.